# The expected type comes from property 'listing' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ListingClientProps'

Tags: react-native, next.js

I got this error, but the app still can working, just likes warning?

```
Type '{ createdAt: string; user: { createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; emailVerified: string | undefined; id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; image: string | null; hashedPassword: string | null; favoriteIds: string[]; }; ... 11 more ...; price: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Omit<GetResult<{ id: string; title: string; description: string; imageSrc: string; createAt: Date; category: string; roomCount: number; bathroomCount: number; guestCount: number; locationValue: string; userId: string; price: number; }, unknown> & {}, "createdAt"> & { ...; } & { ...; }'.
  Type '{ createdAt: string; user: { createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; emailVerified: string | undefined; id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; image: string | null; hashedPassword: string | null; favoriteIds: string[]; }; ... 11 more ...; price: number; }' is not assignable to type '{ user: SafeUser; }'.
    Types of property 'user' are incompatible.
      Type '{ createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; emailVerified: string | undefined; id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; image: string | null; hashedPassword: string | null; favoriteIds: string[]; }' is not assignable to type 'SafeUser'.
        Type '{ createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; emailVerified: string | undefined; id: string; name: string | null; email: string | null; image: string | null; hashedPassword: string | null; favoriteIds: string[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ createdAt: string; updatedAt: string; emailVerified: string | null; }'.
          Types of property 'emailVerified' are incompatible.
            Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.
              Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | null'.ts(2322)
ListingClient.tsx(26, 3): The expected type comes from property 'listing' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ListingClientProps'
```

I tried to checked my code, but cannot found it where has issues.

the interface code is this

```
interface ListingClientProps {
  reservations?: SafeReservation[];
  listing: SafeListing & {
    user: SafeUser;
  };
  currentUser?: SafeUser | null;
}
```

then it'll call here `export type SafeListing = Omit<Listing, "createdAt"> & { createdAt: string; };`

but... where has issues?